# Regex for VisualCode explicitFolding extension

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-group

my custom file has below format, using explicit folding rules i am able to make custom folding for every **[]** , but when i collapse it only collapse 1 line not all lines. **\n** is not accepting in explicit folding extension.

```
[Table]
s1=raw
s2=meta

[Table2]
S2=raw
s1=meta
```

How to make entire [] block to collapse and expand until next []

```
"explicitFolding.rules": {
    "*": {
        "beginRegex": "^\\[.*\\]",
        "endRegex": " "
        }
},
```

Comment: Maybe try `"endRegex": "^\s*$"` if it'll take regex start and end identifiers.

Comment: @Mark did not work, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Is there a regex flags option for Explicit Folding?  If so, add `m` to it.  And you should include a link to that extension to make it easier for people to help you.  And there was a stray space at the beginning of the `endRegex` in my first comment, which I have fixed.

Comment: for folding it always concerns more than 1 line, the extension README should have an example of how to configure such a case

Comment: @Mark tried with space and without in endRegex, and extension doesn't allowed me to pass regex flags.

Comment: "endRegex": "\\[[^\\]]+\\]" is capturing next time [] as well.

Comment: @Mark your suggestion works but needs an extra property, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following setting works for your file format

```json
"explicitFolding.rules": {
  "*": {
    "separatorRegex": "^\\[.*\\]",
    "foldEOF": true
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I had to debug the extension to find out why the suggestion by Mark did not work.

If you have `"endRegex": "^\\s*$"` the regex used to find folds is `a^`. This will **never** be found.

The extension tests if a specified regex (begin. middle, end) matches the empty string. (possible infinite loops, I fixed that in my extension by explicit testing if the next find is actually advancing the `lastIndex` after an `exec()` call, after an issue filed by Mark)

If you want to use `beginRegex` and `endRegex` you can use:

```json
"explicitFolding.rules": {
  "*": {
    "beginRegex": "^\\[.*\\]",
    "endRegex": "^\\s*$",
    "bypassProtection": true,
    "foldEOF": true
  }
}
```

I would suggest to add this folding rule to a particular languageID in the setting.